# How to force a Huawei E3276 LTE modem to only mount as a modem?

Tags: mount, modem

I have a Huawei E3276 LTE USB-modem and I need to force this modem to only mount as a modem when connected to the computer. Per default, the modem also mounts as a CD-drive and a USB mass storage device, which is fine when used with a computer, but a problem when connecting it to a router or similar.

What I've read so far is that you can use PuTTY or similar to connect to the modem over the COM-port, and then send AT-commands to it to configure the modem to only mount as a modem. The AT-command mentioned for most Huawei modems is `AT^U2DIAG=0` but when sending it to my modem I receive `ERROR` in response, which doesn't give me much to work with.

I've also tried `AT^U2DIAG?` which is said to work for some Huawei modems to display the possible values for this property, but that returns `ERROR` as well.

I've tried other AT commands, like `ATI` to get information about model, IMEI etc. which work just fine.

Is there some other command I can use to do this, or is there something else I need to do in order for this to work?

Answer (score 5):

You can use these AT-commands:

```
AT^SETPORT?  - show current mode
AT^SETPORT=? - show available modes
AT^SETPORT="A1,A2;1,2,3" - set "only modem" mode.
```

Make sure you write down the current mode (using the first command), just in case you want to revert any changes at some later time.

After sending these commands you have to reinsert your modem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this command

```
AT^SETPORT="FF;1"
```

This command disables all ports excepting the modem port.

I guess you have already solved your problem but I hope this will help other users having the same problem, since I have spent a couple of hours trying to find the solution.

I have a HUAWEI E3131 modem (issued by RCS-RDS in Romania) and now it works with a Edimax 3g-6200n router

Answer (score 1):

The E3276 is a 4G LTE modem.

```
AT^SETPORT=?

^SETPORT:1: 3G MODEM
^SETPORT:2: 3G PCUI
^SETPORT:3: 3G DIAG
^SETPORT:5: 3G GPS
^SETPORT:A: BLUE TOOTH
^SETPORT:16: NCM
^SETPORT:A1: CDROM
^SETPORT:A2: SD
^SETPORT:10: 4G MODEM
^SETPORT:12: 4G PCUI
^SETPORT:13: 4G DIAG
^SETPORT:14: 4G GPS
```

You can set the 1, 2 and 3 but they will become 10, 12 and 13. You need to send the command:

```
AT^SETPORT="FF;10,12"
```

For Modem and PCUI. If you want the Network Control Model instead of Modem you need to send:

```
AT^SETPORT="FF;12,16"
```

I have mine set for both Modem and NCM that way I can use it on both Android (with PPP Widget) and Mac (with Generic Modem driver dialing *99#) using Modem and on Windows 10 using NCM, that would be:

```
AT^SETPORT="FF;10,12,16"
```

You *NEED* to leave the "PCUI" port or you will "brick" the modem (not be able to send any further commands, and you will be stuck with what you set)

Another note is that "DIAG" is used for DIAGNOSTIC mode and it is not required for connectivity and can be enabled if needed later through the "PCUI", with "DIAG" and the correct firmware you can change quite a few things about the modem.  Just remember to *NEVER* remove "PCUI", very important!

Comment: You can unbrick it though by shortening to ground service pin and powering it up ("needle method"). Pin location shown here: https://youtu.be/SvqCGxTuCHE?t=176